# Oracle Trigger Simple SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am attempting to write this trigger but it is not working right.  I have a table GIVING(donor, receiver, giftname) and a table PERSONS(pname, age, haircolor).  for the trigger I want it to spit out a message whenever the donor and receiver have the same hair color.  Trivial, I know, but I'm just starting to learn triggers and am totally stuck on why this won't work.  Thanks.

```
create or replace TRIGGER SameHairColor
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF GIFTNAME ON GIVING
DECLARE
  haircolordonor varchar(255);
  haircolorreceiver varchar(255);
BEGIN
select persons.haircolor into haircolordonor
from persons, giving
where (donor = persons.pname);
select persons.haircolor into haircolorreceiver
from persons, giving
where (receiver = persons.pname);

if (haircolordonor = haircolorreceiver) then

dbms_output.put_line('Wow, they have the same haircolor!  Who would have thought?');
end if;

end;
```

The error message I get is error during execution "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows", pointing to the row below DECLARE...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not restricting your queries to the donor/receiver of the inserted/updated row. They should look like this:

```
select persons.haircolor
into haircolordonor
from persons
where persons.pname = :NEW.donor;
```

BTW: Your trigger only fires on `INSERT OR UPDATE OF GIFTNAME`, while it should fire on `INSERT OR UPDATE OF donor, receiver` and you need to use `FOR EACH ROW`.

Your trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SameHairColor
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF donor, receiver ON GIVING
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  haircolordonor varchar(255);
  haircolorreceiver varchar(255);
BEGIN
  select persons.haircolor into haircolordonor
  from persons
  where (persons.pname = :NEW.donor);
  select persons.haircolor into haircolorreceiver
  from persons
  where (persons.pname = :NEW.receiver);

  IF (haircolordonor = haircolorreceiver) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Wow, they have the same haircolor!  Who would have thought?');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem and I can run the insert but I don't see the DBMS_output.put_line.  I'm a novice running oracle sql developer but I set server output on which I thought would solve my problem?

Comment: Did you activate "DBMS Output" in SQL-Developer? Does it display messages that you produce in an anomynous block, not in the trigger?

Comment: Yes that is enabled, but it does not display the messages from dbms_output.put_line.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SameHairColor
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF GIFTNAME ON GIVING
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS new
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  haircolordonor varchar(255);
  haircolorreceiver varchar(255);
BEGIN
select persons.haircolor into haircolordonor
from persons, giving
where (:new.donor = persons.pname);
select persons.haircolor into haircolorreceiver
from persons, giving
where (:new.receiver = persons.pname);

if (haircolordonor = haircolorreceiver) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Wow, they have the same haircolor!  Who would have thought?');
end if;

end;
```

Perhaps this might help?

Comment: Yes I tried making it FOR EACH ROW but I still get the same error msg.

Comment: Did you also use the 'new' reference?

Comment: Hmm, strange. Glad you found your solution though :D. It you want to learn more about databases you can checkout http://coursera.org. They have a great db class in video which is free.